# Facebook Application - Unable to get inside FB.getLoginStatus and execute something

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm using the following code:

```
    alert('Inside login status');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //user is logged in and connected
                userid = response.authResponse.userID;
                accesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                alert('Welcome' + response.authResponse.name);
                //return 'connected'
                //do something with user
            }
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //user is logged into facebook but not connected to the app
                //do something
                alert('Like us to get started');
                //return 'not_authorized'
            }
            else {
                //the user even connected to facebook
                //button.innerHTML = 'unknown'
                //button.onclick = function () { login(); }
                alert('login to get started');
                //login();
                //return 'unknown'
            }
        });
```

I have defined the above code in a function that is called in the async init. (The async init is defined in the code behind, I'm registering the script to the head of the page on page load) The first alert is called which means I get into the function, but the rest of it doesn't seem to work. No alerts are displayed after that.

On debugging using breakpoints, I was just directed to the end of the function. No clue why this happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: None of the events that I've subscribed to run. login or logout, nothing seems to get inside the method and display an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have specified correct callback URL in facebook application setting. And If you are testing it on local machine, have you created virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way it runs on my system. I deployed it to a different environment and it worked like a charm.